# Define multi data type for a function with Any or Generic?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I want to define a `function` in `base` and use it in **child** what is **best** way for define it use `Any` or `Generic`?

In **first** **approach** we have something like this :

```
fun jsonObjectToRequestBody(item:Any):RequestBody{
    return RequestBody.create(null, mGson.toJson(item))
}
```

In **second** **approach** we have something like this :

```
fun<T> jsonObjectToRequestBody(item:T):RequestBody{
    return RequestBody.create(null, mGson.toJson(item))
}
```

---

Update:

**tojson() :**

```
  public String toJson(Object src) {
    if (src == null) {
      return toJson(JsonNull.INSTANCE);
    }
    return toJson(src, src.getClass());
  }
```

Comment: It depends. Does the `toJson` method care about the type of `item`? Will it affect the return type of your function in any way? (it doesn't seem to, since `RequestBody` is not generic)

Comment: No it does not care about the type of item and as you said `RequestBody` its not generic.then what is the difference?

Comment: If there's no difference, I guess you can just use `Any`. No need to use generics if it won't help you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is i.e the **Generic** better as this will save you from the overhead of casting the data to desired data type from Any

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please explain more and share a source.

Comment: The desired data-type is a final type (String representation of Json), what is the overhead here (what is need of the casting here)?

Comment: wherever you will invoke this function you will want the data in a specific data type so you have to cast it to that data type from Any that's the overhead and on the other hand if you are using the generic approach you will pass the specific data type in the <> parentheses and the it will automatically return the data type of the object  of the type passed in <>.Hence, no overhead